# Filling NaN cells based on a value in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I've asked a similar question to this and it got no reply, so I thought I'd take a different approach and see if anyone knows how to do this;

First I'll tell you my goal and what I already know:

I am currently cleaning a dataset and need to backward fill the dataset to get rid of some of the `NaN` values.

From the image below

[image: Data]

I would like to backward fill the Na columns of the same X column value, and fill the Na cell with a Y value that has a row value of 1

This image shows what outcome I would like

[image: Data]

I already know I can use

```
 df.loc[df['Y'] == 1] = df.loc[:,].bfill(limit=1)
```

to get it to only fill cells that are matching with a Y value row of 1 (hence the bottom Na cell is not filled).

Here is my question: Using the code above, it fills the middle Na because the Y value to the left is 1, this is fine for the top cell because the source cell and Na cell both have the X value of 1, although for the middle Na there is an X value of 2 and 3. So, is there a way to fill cells that share the same X value down the row? (the X values need to be the same between the source and the Na, if not, nothing happens.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`groupby bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html):

```
df.loc[df['Y'] == 1, 'Z'] = df.groupby('X')['Z'].bfill()
```

`groupby` will ensure that each group of `X` values is treated independently, `bfill` will backfill per group. `df['Y'] == 1` ensures that only rows with `Y` value of 1 will be updated.

`df`:

```
   X  Y    Z
0  1  1  2.0
1  1  2  2.0
2  2  1  NaN
3  3  1  3.0
4  3  2  NaN
5  4  1  4.0
```

---

Initial Frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
                   'Y': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1],
                   'Z': [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]})
```

`df`:

```
   X  Y    Z
0  1  1  NaN
1  1  2  2.0
2  2  1  NaN
3  3  1  3.0
4  3  2  NaN
5  4  1  4.0
```

---

Edit to bfill all columns except X and Y use:

```
df.loc[df['Y'] == 1, df.columns.difference(['X', 'Y'])] = df.groupby('X').bfill()
```

Comment: you are amazing! Thank you so much I've been stuck all day on this! One more thing, instead of saying ,'Z' and ['Z'] is there any way to tell it to fill every cell except for X and Y? I have a lot of cells like Z which need to be filled, over 80 of them, so I don't want to manually change it for every column.

Comment: See the edit for `bfill` all columns except X and Y.

Comment: Henry Ecker @TriggerHappy The problem is that this is for the equivalent values, not the consecutive equivalent values...

Comment: @U11-Foward can you please elaborate I’m slightly confused since I’m new to pandas and data cleaning.

Comment: @TriggerHappy Run both of our programs with `'X': [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4]` you'll see the difference. My solution considers each identical X value in the same group (`Z` -> `[3.0, 2.0, nan, 3.0, nan, 4.0]`). U11's considers the first `1` and the second `1` separate groups. (`Z` -> `[nan, 2.0, nan, 3.0, nan, 4.0]`)

Comment: @Henry Ecker ok I understand, this won’t face a problem in my dataset because all my X values that are identical are beside each other, it reaches up to 5000 in my df and all the x values that are equal are literally next to each other

Comment: And also since I have a limit of 1 parameter on my bfill it wont be an issue

Answer (score 1):

Try using `shift`:

```
df.loc[df['Y'].eq(1) & df['X'].shift(-1).eq(df['X']), 'Z'] = df['Z'].bfill(limit=1)
```